# Arraylist add twice the same information

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm doing a program who compares two Xml documents and compare the name tag to find a duplicated data. When finds I add in an arraylist. But it's adding twice. I search for some wrong but i wasn't able to see. There is the code:

```
public void verificaChave(){
     NodeList v1 = this.doc1.getElementsByTagName("name");
     NodeList v2 = this.doc1.getElementsByTagName("name");
     for(int i= 0; i<v1.getLength();i++)
     {
         found = false;
         for(int j = 0; j<v2.getLength();j++)
         {
             if(v1.item(i).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(v2.item(j).getTextContent()))
             {
                if(!found)
                {                          
                   found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                   repetiu.add(v1.item(i).getTextContent());
                }    
            }     
         }
     }
     this.saveRepeat();
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm off here but the code doesn't make sense: 1) why do you need `found` if you're not using it anywhere ? 2) `v1` and `v2` point to the exact same object - maybe you meant to declare `v2` to point to `doc2` ? 3) you have n^2 iterations: I can only guess that you want the second loop (assuming it runs on the same input) to start from `j = i + 1;` in order not to compare the same objects more than once.

Comment: You're absolutely right, about found I did this code to look in two XML documents, but know I'm comparing in just one, i made some changes but i forgot this one, I changed again and it's worked. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that you're instantiating two completely identical NodeLists - v1 and v2 - and then using a for loop to iterate through v1 and a separate, nested for loop to iterate through v2. There's no reason for v1 to exist at all, and even if you didn't mean for both NodeLists to point to the same document, I can't imagine a case where you'd want to nest iterations like you're doing here.

Additionally, you have a boolean flag found, but you never actually use that value at all - did you mean to use it as a sentinel value somewhere? Another point - there's not really a point in checking whether found == false if you're never going to be setting it back to false. It's less confusing and less verbose to just set found to true if v1.item(i).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(v2.item(j).getTextContent())).

Comment: Yes, I saw what i did wrong and its working know, thanks a lot!! I'm new in programming, thanks to take a time to help me!!

Comment: @GilsonFonseca No problem! If it was helpful, please go ahead and click the check mark to designate this as your selected answer.